# Using TypeScript To Create A React Stateless Functional Component That Accepts Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I want to create a react component  in typescript, imagelist, that displays a list of images, links and numbers.

My json looks something like this

```
{   "_id": "59c8ead6411f1e56f498a71b",   "images": [
    {
      "post_url": "http://www.Facebook.com/974",
      "image_url": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
      "count": 887
    },
    {
      "post_url": "http://www.Facebook.com/711",
      "image_url": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
      "count": 749
    }   ] }
```

I have a dashboard component that looks like this

```
import * as React from 'react'; 
const fakeData = require('./fake_data.json'); 
import ImageList from './ImageList';

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ImageList data={fakeData.images} />
      </div>
    );   } }
```

I have tried to define my imagelist component as follows

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface ImageListValue {
  post_url: string;
  image_url: string;
  count: number;
}

interface ImageListProps {
  data: ImageListValue[];
}

const ImageList = ({ data }: ImageListProps) => {
  return data.map(item => {
    return (
      <div key={item.post_url}>
        <a href={item.post_url}>{item.post_url}</a>
        <img src={item.image_url} />
        <h1>item.count</h1>
      </div>
    );
  });
};

export default ImageList;
```

There linter shows no problems in the ImageList component, but in the Dashboard component I get the following message.

```
JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Property 'render' is missing in type 'Element[]'.
[ts] JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.
```

I'm not sure what this error message means. My first thought was that I needed to use a SFC type definition as described [here][1]
  [1]: https://medium.com/@iktakahiro/react-stateless-functional-component-with-typescript-ce5043466011 .

I changed my code to this

```
const ImageList: React.SFC<ImageListProps> = ({data}) => {
  return data.map(item => {
    return (
      <div key={item.post_url}>
        <a href={item.post_url}>{item.post_url}</a>
        <img src={item.image_url} />
        <h1>item.count</h1>
      </div>
    );
  });
};
```

and received another error

```
[ts]
Type '({ data }: ImageListProps & { children?: ReactNode; }) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<ImageListProps>'.
  Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any> | null'.
    Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'.
      Property 'type' is missing in type 'Element[]'.
const ImageList: React.StatelessComponent<ImageListProps>
```

I'm new to typescript and feel like I am missing some key things. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this error is caused by the data type you're using for `ImageList`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is a bit obscure, but the problem is that your function returns an array of `ReactElement`'s instead of just one (returning an array will be allowed in react 16). If you wrap it in a parent `div` it should work:

```
const ImageList : React.SFC<ImageListProps> = ({data}) => (
  <div>
    { data.map(item => (
        <div key={item.post_url}>
          <a href={item.post_url}>{item.post_url}</a>
          <img src={item.image_url} />
          <h1>item.count</h1>
        </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

(also removed a couple of redundant return statements)

Comment: Can you please provide reference link for Two way binding in ReactJs Stateless Functional Component

Comment: There's no two-way binding here, so I'm not sure what link you're referring to.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been trying to decipher this for way too long.